# Open/Close Divs with separated Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm trying to use images as buttons to show content on a div container, just like the buttons on youtube at the top and left side.

I want to make a few buttons in a row and let them show a certain content on another div.
And because all the contents of every button is showed in the same div, I want the opened content to dissapear when another button is clicked. I allredy know the tabs() function of JQuery, but I haven't found any solution with separated buttons.

EDIT: Code that worked for me, but without separated buttons (what I want to have)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( );
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#tabs {width:100%;height:100%;}

ul {clear:both; background:black;}

li .active {float:left;}

li  {display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab-3">
<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
<p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show a minimum code sample.

Comment: No one who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/vFLxV/) something like you want?

JS

```
$('.text').hide();

$('img').click(function(){
     if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'phooey' )
     {
         $('.holder1').children('.text').toggle('slide');
     }
     if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'dawg' )
     {
         $('.holder2').children('.text').toggle('slide');
     }
     if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'woody' )
     {
         $('.holder3').children('.text').toggle('slide');
     }
```

### });

Edit:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks pretty good, but that's not what I want. I have a div container on the left side and 3 buttons in a div over the content-container. So if one of the buttons is clicked, I want to show a certain content in the div below. If another of the 3 buttons is clicked, I want to hide the currently content in the div below and show another content.

Comment: Ok, here's an update with .hide() to hide anything that has already been clicked - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/vFLxV/1/. Do you really need help moving some of the elements around?

Comment: By removing the divs with the id "title" it's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot

Comment: Okay well... On Fiddle it works very fine, but trying it by myself not on Fiddle doesn't work... Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: None yet... Just tried it out by doing a normal .html document and placing it on my desktop. And the thing that is not working is the Jquery I guess, because the div's are all open and if I click one of the pictures nothing ever happen and yeah I included JQuery 1.9.1 on the document

Comment: Add an alert('help') after one of the .clicks. Make a new <div class='testme'></div> and use $('.testme').html('hello'). If "hello" doesn't show up in the div, there's a problem with the jQuery link.

Comment: Okay.. I tried it out and yep, doesn't work. So... I'm using the same Jquery version (1.9.1) as the script in Fiddle. I'm pretty new to JQuery so does anyone have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: I edited my answer. Add the bottom three lines to the header of your page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, but it's still not working... Here is a link to the code http://hastebin.com/romufaxise.html Maybe someone will find the trouble...

Comment: Put the script just above the </body> tag.

Comment: I downloaded your file, moved the script to above the </body>, uploaded it to my server and it works just fine.

Comment: Okay.. It works this way, thanks a lot. But I'm not really happy with this soulution, because I want the script to be included in the <head> part but with this way it doesn't work... Anyone an idea why or how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you want the script in the head? The DOM needs to load, then you click and the js is run. The "standard" is script before the body.

Comment: So in this case... Is it possible to put the script before the body tag? Because after the </body> tag the browser says that there is a wrong placed <script> tag when I look at the source code even though it works

Comment: <script>js stuff</script></body></html> is standard.

Comment: Okay, so this is solved for me this way. Thanks a lot to you guys and special to you TimSPQR for the help :)